# Can't acces com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider() Java MailApi

Tags: java, api, email

I am  working at an EmailBot which sends lots of Emails. Today I installed Linux for developing. I am using the same IDE. But I'm getting this weird error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider is not accessible

at de.EmeldemelTV.Nice.Packi.EmailSend.main(EmailSend.java:38)
```

(I'm using the Java Mail API)

Comment: can you add the code that throws this error please.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with that class, but I would check version of java. Perhaps you have different jdk on linux and this class was removed in this version.